# Regex for matching strings between '=' and '/' or "=" and end of string

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for regex which can help me replace strings like

```
source=abc/task=cde/env=it --> source='abc'/task='cde'/env='it'
```

To be more precise, I want to replace a string which starts with `=` and ends with either `/` or end of the string with `''`

Tried code like this

```
"source=abc/task=cde/env=it".replaceAll("=(.*?)/","'$1'")
```

But that results in

```
source'abc'task'cde'env=it
```

Comment: Are all of these values in the same string? And what have you tried? You even mention regex, where is your attempt?

Comment: @f1sh I tried code like this but it only matches first two strings not the last one `"source=abc/task=cde/env=it".replaceAll("=(.*?)/","'$1'") ` but what I get is source'abc'task'cde'envit

Comment: Please post the regex you tried.

Comment: @f1sh Posted my regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
String input = "source=abc/task=cde/env=it".replaceAll("=(.*?)(/|$)","='$1'/");
```

The problems I found are that you are not replacing the `=`
and also the `/` is not there for the end of String, that also needs to be replaced when found.

**output**

```
source='abc'/task='cde'/env='it'/
```

If you don't want the last '/', that is trivial to remove isn't it.

Comment: thanks that might work. I don't need that last `/` though. I can always remove last character by post processing but is there a way we can handle it in regex ?

Comment: Yep, the answer by @ChrisFoley

Answer (score 1):

Using lookahead and look behind:

```
(?<==)([^/]*)((?=/)|$)
```

Lookbehind allows you to specify what comes before your match. In this case an equals: `(?<==)`.

The main match in my regex looks for any non-slash character, zero or more times: `([^/]*)`

Lookahead allows you to specify what comes after your match. In this case, a slash: `(?=/)`.

The `$` matches the end of the line, so that the last item in your test data becomes quoted. `((?=/)|$)` combines with this with the lookahead, meaning "either a slash comes after the match or this is the end of the line".

Here it is in action in a test.

```
@Test 
public void test_quote_items() {
    String regex = "(?<==)([^/]*)((?=/)|$)";
    String actual = "source=abc/task=cde/env=it".replaceAll(regex,"'$1'");
    String expected = "source='abc'/task='cde'/env='it'";
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: *Using lookahead and look behind:* please explain for people who have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Great suggestion @ScaryWombat. I have added an explanation. Thanks!